# How to set a value for MSBuild property using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, msbuild, powershell-2.0, msbuild-4.0

I have a property to specify the build drive:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDrive Condition="'$(BuildDrive)'==''">Y:</Group>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If I want to change the build drive using a batch file, I can do as follows:

```
@echo off

set buildDrive=H:

:: Then call MSBuild

Msbuild /t:BuildTarget %Projectfile% %Logger%
```

Now I want achieve the same using PowerShell.

I tried as follows in my PowerShell script, build.ps1:

```
$BuildDrive=H:
MSbuild /t:BuildTarget $ProjectFile $Logger
```

But it is not honoring the drive letter provided through $BuildDrive.
I knew I could achieve it if I passed a parameter as follows, but when the number of properties are more, this approach was not handy.

```
$BuildDrive=H:
Msbuild /t:BuildTarget /p:BuildDrive=$BuildDrive $projectfile $logger
```

How do I pass a `PropertyGroup` value through PowerShell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting environment variables. These are available as properties in MSBuild.

You can do the following in PowerShell:

```
$env:BuildDrive="H:"
```

Comment: I think Builddrive is my own property , even if i have some property name called dummy and the condition is specified  then it can be replaced by batch file.<PropertyGroup>
        <Dummy Condition="'$(Dummy)'==''">Y:</Group>
</PropertyGroup>

I

Comment: @Samselvaprabu - I don't understand what you are trying to say. Did you try the line given in my answer in your script?

Comment: Wow. It works. So when condition is being passed to propertygroup, it will be considered as environment variable. is it so?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu - Read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459(v=VS.100).aspx . Also, accept as answer ( tick on the left )